# how to remove a symlink from /usr/bin/python in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, python

I was trying to solve a problem and unfortunately used this command in terminal

`sudo ln -sf python2.7.12 /usr/bin/python`

Which screwed my python installation. Now, when I type `python` in the terminal it gets idle and shows nothing. How can I revert it back? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and python 2.7.12

Because of this, `pip` is also stopped working and showing this error,

```
unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have accidentally created a link at `/usr/bin/python` which points to a file called `/python2.7.12`.

This would usually give you an error saying that `/usr/bin/python` already exists, but because you used the `-f` (force) flag. It deleted that file before it put the new link in. If I were you I wouldn't use the `-f` flag at all.

If you do ever need to overwrite a file, I would reccomend using `rm -i` to manually delete it before creating the linik with `ln -s`

To fix this you just have to recreate the old link by running

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

## IMPORTANT

When you are using `ln` you have to put the file that you are linking to **first** and have the name of the link second. See the man page: [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html).

NOTE: You should always read the man page for a command before using it.

Comment: IIRC it will effectively point to `/usr/bin/python2.7.12` rather than `/python2.7.12` (from `man ln`: *"a relative link is interpreted in relation to its parent directory."*

Comment: @steeldriver Really? I will check that when I get access to a linux computer. The man page that I had linked to mentioned a `-r` flag that allows relative links. Also I have tried to make relative links before and it failed. Probably because i didn't know about the `-r` tag.

Comment: ... for example, to change `/bin/sh` from`dash` to `bash` and vice versa you can use `ln -sf bash /bin/sh` and `ln -sf dash /bin/sh` (which will actually link to `/bin/bash` and `/bin/dash` respectively)

Comment: @steeldriver So it's relative to the link, not the current directory?

Comment: @steeldriver Can I change `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python` to `sudo ln -s python2 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: This doesn't work at all in 2020 because OSX prevents doing things in `/usr/`. I have no solution yet.